# Split number in to case and units in excel

Tags: excel

I have a sheet to count stock, it is counted in units eg

26 bottles

In another column I want it to work out full boxes and left over units

Box is 24 units so would display 1 box and 2 units not just 26

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
INT(cell_val/24) to get box numbers
```

and

```
MOD(cell_val,24) to get units.
```